# Why can I get a ticket for a service when no object in Active Directory has a matching servicePrincipalName attribute?

Tags: active-directory

I am able to obtain a service ticket for a service:

```
$  kvno HTTP/somehost.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
HTTP/somehost.exapmle.com@EXAMPLE.COM: kvno = 91
```

However there appears to be no object in AD with a matching `serverPrincipalName` attribute. I've run `setspn -Q HTTP/somehost.example.com` which outputs the message `No such SPN found.` I've also searched the domain with the filter `(servicePrincipalName=HTTP/somehost.example.com)` and haven't found any object with a matching `servicePrincipalName` object.

**What's going on here?** Is there some hidden mechanism that lets computer objects have SPNs that are generated on demand/behind the scenes/in a way that means that they don't show up in the directory in the expected way?

---

When I examine the relevant computer object in AD, I can see that it *does* have several `servicePrincipalName` attributes, but none of them have `HTTP` as their primary component:

```
$ ldapsearch -s base -b CN=somehost,OU=Some OU,DC=example,DC=com servicePrincipalName
dn: CN=somehost,OU=Some OU,DC=example,DC=com
servicePrincipalName: CmRcService/somehost
servicePrincipalName: CmRcService/somehost.example.com
servicePrincipalName: WSMAN/somehost
servicePrincipalName: WSMAN/somehost.example.com
servicePrincipalName: TERMSRV/somehost.example.com
servicePrincipalName: RestrictedKrbHost/somehost.example.com
servicePrincipalName: HOST/somehost.example.com
servicePrincipalName: TERMSRV/somehost
servicePrincipalName: RestrictedKrbHost/somehost
servicePrincipalName: HOST/somehost
```

Comment: I've created a separate user account and I'm able to add HTTP/somehow.example.com to its `msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo` attribute, and I'm able to use protocol transition to get tickets to the service on behalf of other users. Since there's still no object in AD with a matching `servicePrincipalName` attribute, I'm still unsure as to exactly what I'm delegating to...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setspn -Q` to check if a SPN is registered in AD and who owns it:

```
setspn -Q HTTP/somehost.example.com
```

Comment: I'll find a friendly Windows user to run that and report back...

Comment: The command outputs `No such SPN found.`